# Permission Denied Issue : setfacl

Tags: linux, access-control-list, permissions

I have tried to set Extended ACL for the folder ssam and ended 
with a "Permission Denied" message at the end.

I have made sure that the ACL is enabled and is added in /etc/fstab for /home.
Below are the details.

```
[root@localhost boot]# cat config-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 | grep POSIX_ACL
CONFIG_EXT2_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_EXT3_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_XFS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_TMPFS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
[root@localhost boot]#
```

Below is my /etc/fstab where I have enabled acl for the /home directory.

```
[root@localhost boot]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Mar 14 13:54:35 2013
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=e4dd1184-719a-43b3-bc3b-3597eff17209 /     ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=f91a2e20-ef6d-4394-bc24-3ef4745055e6 /boot ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=c587798e-f13f-42fe-b6d2-7f009c9b8c72 /home ext4    defaults,acl    1 2
UUID=d691e668-6a9e-41af-b225-76dfd2463abf /usr  ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=4c2ed75e-f536-43c9-a9a0-efbaa097a3f0 swap  swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/media/Films            /dev/Films/Vol_Films    ext4    rw              0 0
```

and this is what I have done with setfacl (Kindly note that ssam is the home folder for the user ssam)

```
root@localhost home]# setfacl -d -m u:chandu:rwx,m:rwx ssam
[root@localhost home]# getfacl ssam
# file: ssam
# owner: ssam
# group: ssam
user::rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:chandu:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

[root@localhost home]# su chandu
[chandu@localhost home]$ cd ssam
bash: cd: ssam: Permission denied
[chandu@localhost home]$
```

I appreciate your suggestions in solving this problem.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set **default** ACLs only! That are those for **new** objects created in this directory. You need this command:

```
setfacl -m u:chandu:rwx ssam
```